# Работа принтера в Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: принтер, ubuntu

Помогите настроить принтер Canon LBP-810 в Ubuntu 11.10. Я совсем чайник, находил много разных примеров в Инете, но ничего кривыми руками (может и мозгами) сделать не могу. Вот, если бы именно мой случай с пошаговым исполнением, тогда может и выйдет. Спасибо всем заранее.

Answer (score 1):

Установка принтера делается через запуск [скрипта](http://codebin.cotescu.com/canon/lbp_driver/CanonCAPTdriver.tar.gz) со страницы [how to install Canon LBP printers in Ubuntu](http://radu.cotescu.com/how-to-install-canon-lbp-printers-in-ubuntu/).

```
tar -zxvf raducotescu-CanonCAPTdriver-release-2.4-0-gc8ea9f9.tar.gzcd raducotescu-CanonCAPTdriver-release-2.4-0-gc8ea9f9sudo ./canonLBP_install.sh 1120
```

И должно заработать.